# Can't run SQL query via SQL job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
select tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb2.col4, tb2.col7
from server_1.database_a.dbo.table_1 tbl1
inner join server_2.database_c.dbo.table_2 tbl2 on tbl1.col_id = tbl2.col_id
```

This query runs fine (I had to create an link on the sql server to link the 2 servers for the query to work) when I manually execute it from within `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`.  But when I try to create an sql job which executes this query once every day, I get the following error message and the query does not execute

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The object name
>   'server_1.database_a.dbo.table_1' contains more than the maximum
>   number of prefixes. The maximum is 2. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 117). 
>   The step failed.

Comment: What the 3 servers versions? That error is listed as a breaking change to SQL 2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx

Comment: Are you using 3 servers or the job is running in the server_1? in that case just get rid of server_1.database_a prefix.

Comment: Both servers are based on Sql Server 2008 R2 and yes, the job is running on one of the servers, so the query is based on 2 servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
use database_a;
select tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb2.col4, tb2.col7
from dbo.table_1 tbl1
inner join server_2.database_c.dbo.table_2 tbl2 on tbl1.col_id = tbl2.col_id
```

Answer (score 0):

server_1.database_1.dbo.table_1 this is not the same with you write first. Its:
server_1.database_a.dbo.table_1 may be the reason is this.

Comment: Sorry, it's correct in my actual script, the error you spotted was a typo in the question.  I've corrected the script in the question now.  Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user in sysadmin server role.
2. Add this user into linked server login mappings with remote user name and pwd
   in security tab of linked server properties.